# C signal handling error, issue child-parent contact

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork

**GOAL**: Make parent process counters correct, counter1 = 5, counter2 =8.

Program is supposed to create 2 subprocesses. Each one of them will send set number of respectively SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 to parent. 5 and 8 times respectively.

To simplify, after many crashes causing my system to log out, closing all programs and forcing me to log in, i'm printing information about parent process instead. The goal is to replace those prints by 
`kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1)` // and SIGUSR2 for second child process.

Current child work function:

```
void childWork(int loopCounter, int sigNum)
{
    for(; loopCounter>0; loopCounter--)
    {
        if(SIGUSR1==sigNum) //kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1); 
            printf("[%d] sending SIGUSR1 to %d\n", getpid(),getppid());
        else if(SIGUSR2 == sigNum) //kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
            printf("[%d] sending SIGUSR2 to %d\n", getpid(),getppid());
    }
}
```

Here is the zombie handling function for cleanup:

```
void handleZombie(int sig) {
    while (1) {
            pid_t pid = waitpid(0, NULL, WNOHANG);
            if (pid < 0) {
                    if (errno == ECHILD)
                            return;
                    printf("Error, cleaning\n");
            }
            if (pid == 0)
                    return;


    }
```

And finally main:

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("[%d] PARENT started! My parent: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    childrenLeft=2;
    setHandler(handleZombie,SIGCHLD);
    setHandler(sigHandler1, SIGUSR1);
    setHandler(sigHandler2, SIGUSR2);
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=childrenLeft;i++)
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0)
            printf("Error - fork\n");
        if(pid==0)
            if(i==1)
            {
                printf("[%d] child created!\n", getpid());
                childWork(5,SIGUSR1);
            }
            if(i==2)
            {
                childWork(8, SIGUSR2);
                printf("[%d] child created!\n", getpid());
            }
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    printf("Work finished, final numbers:\nSIGUSR1 received: %d\nSIGUSR2 received: %d\n",sig1Count,sig2Count);
    while (wait(NULL) > 0)
                continue;
    printf("[PARENT=%d] terminates\n", getpid());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Current issue is actually handling the parent process. For reason i do not understand, my second child isn't created. What more, the parent being printed is out of the blue.

```
[6025] PARENT started! My parent: 1300
[6026] child created!
[6026] sending SIGUSR1 to 6025
[6026] sending SIGUSR1 to 6025
[6026] sending SIGUSR1 to 6025
[6026] sending SIGUSR1 to 30404
[6026] sending SIGUSR1 to 30404
```

This is the complete output. Please help me understand what is going on here...

Comment: "being kicked out of system back to the logging screen". We don't know how your system is set up so cannot tell you how it is possible that running a simple program would log you out of the system.

Comment: It seems like the reason could be a simple as killing the parent process. If the children are getting handled by init, then it would make sense. Therefore i'l start searching for a place where parent finishes before children, and its children are handed over.

Comment: Not sure what you mean at all. Running your program should not affect the parent process (which is likely the shell). It's not clear what the behaviour of your program is. Please provide the exact output log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you don't report that child 2 is created until after `childWork()` returns.

However, your fundamental problem is the lack of statement grouping braces after `if (pid == 0)` which means that the `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS):` after the two tests `if (i == 1)` and `if (i == 2)`; causes the parent to exit immediately after launching the first child.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("[%d] PARENT started! My parent: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    childrenLeft=2;
    setHandler(handleZombie,SIGCHLD);
    setHandler(sigHandler1, SIGUSR1);
    setHandler(sigHandler2, SIGUSR2);
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=childrenLeft;i++)
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0)
            printf("Error - fork\n");
        if(pid==0)
        {   // Primary bug: braces missing
            if(i==1)
            {
                printf("[%d] child created!\n", getpid());
                childWork(5,SIGUSR1);
            }
            if(i==2)
            {
                printf("[%d] child created!\n", getpid());  // Moved before childWork()
                childWork(8, SIGUSR2);
            }
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);    // Only executed by children
        }   // Primary bug: missing braces
    }

    printf("Work finished, final numbers:\nSIGUSR1 received: %d\nSIGUSR2 received: %d\n",sig1Count,sig2Count);
    while (wait(NULL) > 0)
                continue;
    printf("[PARENT=%d] terminates\n", getpid());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is the bare minimum fixing needed; there are many other changes that could and perhaps should be made.

Comment: This definitely is embarrassing. Thank you for pointing this silly mistake out. I've spent too much time on this snippet, even if that's no excuse for bad quality code. I've started over with the example above, and managed to partially achieve one goal - 2 children sending the same signal to parent, which is caught by a handler incrementing global counter. However I also read that due to signal merging and race conditions, not all signals can be caught. That explains why i get different counter every time. Is there a simple solution to maximize quality of this counting?

Comment: You don't show `setHandler()` so we can't tell whether you're using `signal()` or `sigaction()` to organize the signal handling.  If you use `sigaction()` (as you should), you can arrange to block SIGUSR1 while you're handling SIGUSR2 and vice versa — that should probably fix your problem. We haven't got your `sigHandler1()` or `sigHandler2()` functions either; there may be relevant information in those. However, were you to want more help, you should probably ask a new question rather than try editing this question. 'Chameleon questions' are frowned upon; they aren't fair on those who answer.